# error: C compiler cannot create executables on Mac OSX 10.7.5 Lion

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-lion

I have a similar problem to [c compiler cannot create executable on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642539/c-compiler-cannot-create-executable-on-mac).  It looks like the final suggestion on that thread was to uninstall gcc.  Is there any way around this without uninstalling gcc?  I seem to remember installing gcc to make another piece of software work properly, and I'm afraid uninstalling it may cause other issues.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Here is more information:

I'm running OSX 10.7.5 Lion, I have GCC version 4.2.1, and XCode 4.4.1 with the Command Line Tools installed.

I was trying to install an IRAF package called cfitsio when this error occurred, following the directions at http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/mac_universal_binary.html:

unpack the cfitsio source code tar file
cd cfitsio
setenv CFLAGS "-arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2"
Then proceed with the standard cfitsio build, i.e.:
./configure
make
make install

The problem is that I get errors at the ./configure step, having to do with gcc.  Here is the config.log:

```
--------------Begin config.log----------------------

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = vpnls09.ctio.noao.edu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 11.4.2
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 165 tasks, 1106 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 0.39, Mach factor: 7.60
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /Users/kaleida/anaconda/bin
PATH: /Users/kaleida/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /sw/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2107: checking build system type
configure:2121: result: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
configure:2141: checking host system type
configure:2154: result: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
configure:2174: checking target system type
configure:2187: result: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
configure:2348: checking for gcc
configure:2364: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2375: result: gcc
configure:2604: checking for C compiler version
configure:2613: gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2624: $? = 0
configure:2613: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configure:2624: $? = 0
configure:2613: gcc -V >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2624: $? = 1
configure:2613: gcc -qversion >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
configure:2624: $? = 1
configure:2644: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2666: gcc -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/23/wqjyjh2s0fb4_kss3f9cr_zc0000gn/T//ccFUu7Aa.out
configure:2670: $? = 255
configure:2708: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2713: error: in `/Users/kaleida/src/cfitsio':
configure:2715: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
ARCH=''
ARCHIVE=''
CC='gcc'
CFITSIO_MAJOR='3'
CFITSIO_MINOR='37'
CFITSIO_SHLIB=''
CFITSIO_SHLIB_SONAME=''
CFITSIO_SONAME='2'
CFLAGS='-arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77_WRAPPERS=''
FC=''
GCCVERSION=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_ROOT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPRE=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIB_LD=''
SHLIB_SUFFIX=''
SSE_FLAGS=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin11.4.2'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin11.4.2'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
my_shmem=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin11.4.2'
target_vendor='apple'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77

--------------End config.log----------------------
```

Here is some more information about gcc on my machine:

```
[vpnls09:~] kaleida% which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
[vpnls09:~] kaleida% gcc -version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
[vpnls09:~] kaleida% gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I also tested gcc with a "Hello World" script:

```
[vpnls09:~/src] kaleida% more hello.c 
/* hello.c - demo for os x */ 
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void){ 
 printf("Hello world\n"); 
 return 0; 
} 
[vpnls09:~/src] kaleida% gcc -o hello.o -c hello.c 
[vpnls09:~/src] kaleida% make hello 
cc hello.o -o hello 
[vpnls09:~/src] kaleida% ./hello 
Hello world
```

Any ideas for how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the error message!